# Send AJAX request without submitting the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms

The idea that  when the user filling the booking info, he need to verify his phone number in the form where he receive the code and put it with rest of booking info before submitting , so I have the following view

```
<%= form_for(@booking) do |f| %>
    <%= current_or_not_authenticated_user.email %>
    <br>
    <%= f.label :patient_id %>
    <%= f.collection_select :patient_id, User.order(:created_at), :id, :email %>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#patientModal">
      New Patient
    </button>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :type %>
      <%= f.select :booking_type, options_for_select([['Physiologist'], ['Psychiatrist'], ['Pediatrician']]) %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :customer_id, :value => current_or_not_authenticated_user.id %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :address %>
      <%= f.collection_select :address_id, Address.where(user_id: current_or_not_authenticated_user.id), :id, :address1 %>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addressModal">
        New Address
      </button>
      <% if current_user && !current_user[:verified_by_phone_at]   %>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= label_tag(:phone) %>
            <%= text_field_tag(:phone) %>
            <button id="smsBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send SMS</button>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= label_tag :code %>
            <%= text_field_tag :code %>
          </div>
      <% end %>
      <%= f.submit "Confirm Booking" %>
    </div>
    <br>
<% end %>


    <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#smsBtn').on('click', function () {
          $.ajax({
            url: <%=phone_verification_index_path %>,
            type: 'ajax',
            data: $('#code').val()
          });

        });

      });

    </script>
```

clicking on smsbtn should go to phone_verification controller which in turn call third party method that send sms to the user, then the user fill his code and click on submit.

my problem is when the user click on smsbtn, the @booking form get submitted and I don't want to form submit unless the user click on Confirm Booking, the only way that my jquery was working, was when I moved both phone field and smsbtn outside form.

the order of the fields is important because I don't want the user to find code field first then phone field under it.

Comment: If you want to share a controller method, usually, I pull it out into a helper and then have the 'other' controller include the helper.  (look at helper() method in ApplicationController)

Comment: @Medo, I don't think the title of your question matches with the actual problem. You simply want to do an AJAX request without submitting the form.

Comment: @Leito you are right, I have changed the title to reflect what I actually want

Comment: <button type="button"> should not submit the form, so something strange is going on. Did you try <input type="button"> ?

Answer (score 1):

You want to prevent *#smsBtn* from submitting the form, this can be done in different ways, one of it is to call `event.preventDefault()` on the click handler:

```
$('#smsBtn').on('click', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Hard to tell why, without knowing your entire setup. Know that you know better what you are looking for you should be able to find a better answer by searching again: "Prevent button form submitting form." You will find this and other answers that might help and even understand why this isn't working for you. Good Luck